# Показ модального окна из другого файла в React Native

Tags: javascript, функции, react-native, expo

Есть два файла: `ModalWidget.js` (внешний файл виджета) и `HomeScreen.js` (основная форма). Нужно, чтобы по нажатию кнопки, появлялось модальное окно, реализованное в файле пользовательского виджета, и исчезало по клику кнопки на самом виджете. Моя реализация не работает: кнопка не показывает модальное окно.

**ModalWidget.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, Modal } from 'react-native';

export function ModalWidget(modalState) {

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(modalState);

  return (
    <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
      >
      <Button
        title="Close"
        onPress={setModalVisible(false)}
      />
    </Modal>

  )
};
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { ModalWidget } from '../components/ModalWidget';

export default function HomeScreen() {

  const [modalState, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ModalWidget
        state={modalState}
      />
      <Button
        title="Open"
        onPress={setModalVisible(true)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Как изменять состояние модального окна извне и из самого этого окна, чтобы его можно было открывать с основного экрана, а закрывать по нажатию кнопки на нём? Пробовал сделать глобальный state hook таким образом (в файле ModalWidget), чтобы его можно было изменять дополнительной функцией, но появлялась ошибка `Invariant Violation: Invalid Hook call`, то есть, как я понимаю, так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получил ответ на англоязычном StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140730/change-state-of-modal-widget-outside-its-class-in-react-native

Реализовал так:

**ModalWidget.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, Modal } from 'react-native';

export function ModalWidget(modalProps) {

  return (
    <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={true}
      >
      <Button
        title="Close"
        onPress={modalProps.closeModal()}
      />
    </Modal>

  )
};
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { ModalWidget } from '../components/ModalWidget';

export default function HomeScreen() {

  const [modalState, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {
        modalState &&
        <ModalWidget
          closeModal={() => {setModalVisible(false)}}
        />
      }
      <Button
        title="Open"
        onPress={setModalVisible(true)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```